# Angular.js, Highcharts, Phantomjs PDF printer - graphs not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, highcharts, phantomjs

I have a very odd problem. I have an Angular.js application that utilizes Highcharts as a graph rendering library. This application has to support printing to PDF, which is done using Phantomjs PDF service used in our company.

Graphs are generated using custom directive. Simplified code:

```
app.directive('metricsChartMulti', [
    function () {
        return {
            ...
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

                ...

                // plot data after they are loaded
                scope.$on('DATA_LOAD_SUCCESS', function() {

                    var chartOptions = {
                        series: scope.series
                        ...
                    };

                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);

                });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

The series data (scope.series) are prepared in the controller which adds them to the scope. Everything works perfectly in the browser with no error. However, **when I call PDF creation service based on Phantomjs2 the graphs are not rendered in the returned PDF file**.

I tried to find an error in the code, but I belive I created the app using the common best practices of Angular framework. After long debugging I found out that **when I change scope.series to a static mock of data, the PDF is plotted correctly**.

In the browser (Chrome, Firefox) this makes no visible change.

I also tried to generate PDFs using different URLs directly from Highcharts website and PDFs were created properly. To me that means there is no problem with company's PDF service.

Any idea how to sort out this awkward situation? Thank you.

Comment: Sound like your `DATA_LOAD_SUCCESS` event should be setting up `scope.series` but it isn't? Try logging it before assigning it to `chartOptions.series` and see if it contains the expected data.

Comment: Well, scope.series is set up by a controller. The data are there, even when I log them in the console... :(

Comment: In the browser, yes, but through Phantomjs I mean. Because that's where it's missing, if I understand everything correctly?

Comment: @Jan I tried to log it out using Phantomjs. The scope.series property is there and it is filled with correct data.

Comment: Maybe the create command gets triggered before the `DATA_LOAD_SUCCESS` event has time to trigger then? Or before the charts have had time to render correctly? I don't know, clutching at straws here, but if the data is the same, then another thing that may be different is timing and order of commands. If I were you I'd try setting up a MCVE for yourself. Just remove code until you get it to work, and then look at what you removed and how that made it work.

Comment: I tried to create another chained event that is broadcasted by parent controller which was fired at the end of the chain. It didn't helped. I tried to add longer timeouts. I also tried to install phantomjs2 locally and also wkhtmltopdf program. Everything with the same result. Blank graphs...

Comment: @tomexx can u plz share the complete code for chart directive and your controller in which you are setting the chart options and broadcasting the msg to directive. Also can u plz explain that can we use on directive for all kind of charts in higchart i.e, spline,bar , column,pie etc.etc. Also I am very thankful to you if you share the code for exporting the page to pdf. Actually I have made a single page application using angular and used highchart and I need to export its views into pdf. My email is aamersaeed2368@hotmail.com plz share the code or send me on email. Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

So what finally helped was a **deep clone** of the scope.series object within the directive.

```
var series = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(scope.series));
```

To me it is kind of awkward solution, but at least it is working now.

Comment: Just as one final thing, could you compare your "cloned" object with the original one and see if they're completely identical? Because that's not really a deep clone unless`scope.series` is completely serializable as JSON. Otherwise, if the only thing different between the two is that the new one points to a different object, it's possible you're modifying/clearing `scope.series` somewhere else in your code. thus invalidating the content of the `chartOptions.series` property.